# 4-adic numbers and zero divisors

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

The $p$-adic numbers form an integral domain provided that $p$ is prime.

Let's look at the $n$-adic numbers when $n$ is not prime.

Case $n = 10$

There are zero divisors.  See [this previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1919274/why-are-p-adic-numbers-and-p-adic-integers-only-defined-for-p-prime/1919299#1919299).

Case $n = pq$ where $p$ and $q$ are coprime (not necessarily prime but not $1$).

There are also zero divisors.  A similar construction works.

Case $n = p^k$ where $p$ is prime and $k > 1$

I have not figured this one out yet, not even the simplest case of $n = 4$.  The construction in the previous question above does not work and I have not found an alternative yet.  Looking at approximations in $\mathbb{Z}_4$, $\mathbb{Z}_{16}$, 
$\mathbb{Z}_{64}$, etc just leads me to zeros divisors ending in zeroes suggesting, but not proving, that there are none.

Note that I am using $\mathbb{Z}_n$ for the integers modulo $n$ and not the $n$-adic numbers.  I think that I have seen it used for both.  What is usual if you want discuss both at the same time?

Another [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2676503/p-adic-numbers-number-theory) asks why $4$-adic numbers are not possible.  The answer seems to be that they are possible but a norm cannot be defined.  So, it leaves the existence of zero divisors open.

Are there zero divisors in the $4$-adic numbers?
Are there idempotents in the $4$-adic numbers?

I have not looked at $9$-adic or other prime powers yet.

Please don't answer directly but some hints would be appreciated.

Comment: I would expect that we have something like $\mathbb{Z}_{p^k} = \mathbb{Z}_p$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{ab} = \mathbb{Z}_a \times \mathbb{Z}_b$, but I didn't check it.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen That suggests another question.  What are the possibilities?  To avoid additional questions and answers hidden in comments, I will post another question unless you can point me to an existing answer.

Comment: as a hint, if you imagine converting from base 4 to base 2, not much changes.

Comment: @Steven Thanks.  I figured that out now.  I briefly considered the 100-adic numbers and it was obviously that they were essentially the same as the 10-adic.

Comment: In answer to your question I understand $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ is better for cyclic groups, especially when used in the setting of p-adic numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If one defines the $4$-adic numbers as the inverse limit
$$\Bbb Z_4\cong\lim_{\longleftarrow}(\Bbb Z/4^n\Bbb Z)$$
then $\Bbb Z_4\cong\Bbb Z_2$, the $2$-adic numbers.

In general $\Bbb Z_{p^k}\cong\Bbb Z_p$.

Comment: Thanks - that's an answer that I had not suspected yet.  It explains why I could not find any zero divisors.  Also, reviewing my attempts at finding them, I see that maybe I should have suspected this.

Comment: It’s fairly simply seen: the families $\{p^n\Bbb Z\}$ and $\{p^{2n}\Bbb Z\}$ are coterminal: each member of the one family contains a member of the other; and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

In "p-adic Analysis Compared with Real" from Svetlana Katok it is proven that for distinct primes $p_1,\ldots,p_k$ we have $\mathbb{Q}_g = \mathbb{Q}_{p_1} \oplus \ldots \oplus \mathbb{Q}_{p_k}$. She doesn't mention the case of non-distinct primes. Moreover she mentions that Hensel proved the above fact.

Comment: Thanks.  We also have, from Lord Shark, $\Bbb Z_{p^k}\cong\Bbb Z_p$ so between the two results, we have the whole story.

Comment: I would pay a bit attention there. The $g$-adic numbers in Katok are defined via a pseudo-norm which is defined analogously to the $p$-adic norm. I am not sure if one can obtain the $g$-adic integers like this if you define them via the inverse limit.

Comment: Thanks.  I have some more study to do.